# how can I create paypal recurring profile in paypal payflow?

Tags: paypal, recurring

I need to create recurring profile using payflow. Is there any good library for this which I can use.

I know what parameters I have to pass. But, which method I need to call is confusing me. I am new to this. So, I am not getting exactly what I have to do. I have my payflow details. I can login into my manager.paypal.com and I can see its activated. I have used angelleye library. But, there isn't any library for creating recurring profile using PayFlow.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with PHP?  If so, my [class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) would make this easy for you.  You would just open up the PayFlowTransaction.php template and fill in the parameters you need accordingly.  It handles the rest.